# Spring Boot + Security + Multi HTTP Web Configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to do an example using spring-boot with spring security.  My idea is to create a web app and also provide an API, I would like to both have security; so I need to create a multi http web security configuration however it is not working.

I followed this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity but no success.  And, I'm getting this error

**Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer to already built object**

The configuration that I'm using is the following:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration { 

@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("12345").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("admin").password("12345").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiConfigurationAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class WebConfigurationAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()                    
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after a lot of reading I found something that works for me:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "customUserDetailsService")
    protected CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Resource(name = "restUnauthorizedEntryPoint")
        private RestUnauthorizedEntryPoint restUnauthorizedEntryPoint;
        @Resource(name = "restAccessDeniedHandler")
        private RestAccessDeniedHandler restAccessDeniedHandler;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityXAuthConfigurerAdapter = new XAuthTokenConfigurer(
                    userDetailsServiceBean());

            // @formatter:off
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**").csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(restUnauthorizedEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(restAccessDeniedHandler)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .and()
                        .apply(securityXAuthConfigurerAdapter);
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
            ;
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced the same issue. But I got it solved when I **extend the WebSecurityConfiguration master class from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.**

Kindly refer the following stackoverflow post in which you can find the full configuration.

[Spring Security HTTP Basic for RESTFul and FormLogin for web - Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774742/spring-security-http-basic-for-restful-and-formlogin-for-web-annotations/27833237#27833237)

Answer (score 0):

I found I could solve this problem by annotating my class with
`@EnableWebSecurity` after reading this hint: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/189#issuecomment-229552207