# Spring security provider for web login and api security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, asp.net-web-api

I am building a web service which uses spring mvc 4 as the framework. My web service has apis which has a signature of /api/v1/apiname

My services are called by external services and which has to be authenticated. I prefer to use a pre Authorised token for the service which i can read and do the authorisation.

In case of my website, which is hosted on the same service uses an sso to sign on which basically uses cookies to authenticate the user.

I developed a partial code which supports login using header token and SSO. But I need to ensure that all api should return me 401 in case not authenticated, and web page access should redirect to external sso service authentication purpose.

```
http.anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/protected**").denyAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new CookieAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Here the CookieAuthenticationFilter will do the cookie based authentication... My problem here is, incase of all api request should return 401 as status and all other requests should redirect to an external service incase of un authorised access. How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be very similar to the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856557/spring-boot-how-to-configure-multiple-login-pages/31899440).  You will need to configure multiple HttpSecurity objects and you can configure different behavior for each.  The [Spring documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) has a decent example.