# Spring Boot: 2 different login pages for 2 URLs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application. I have 2 login pages for 2 different sets of users in the system.

1. Any URL starting with `/expert`, the user should have the role of either `EXPERT` or `ADMIN`. The user uses form login to login into the system, and the login page path is `/login`.
2. For some URLs, such as `css`, `js`, etc, no authentication is required.
3. For all other URLs, the user needs no special role, an authentication is enough. The login page for the user should be `/loginTwo`.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575907/spring-boot-and-spring-security-multiple-login-pages) stackoverflow question and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) documentation to implement this. However, when I access a URL that contains `/expert`, it takes me to the login page `/loginTwo`, instead of `/login`.

Here is my code below:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ExpertWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll();
        http
            .antMatcher("/expert/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_EXPERT')")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }
}

@Configuration
public static class StudentWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Here in stu");

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**,/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/student/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/filter/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/loginTwo").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_EXPERT')")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf();
        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/loginTwo").permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(20)
                .expiredUrl("/loginTwo")
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);
        http
            .headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN));
    }
}
```

Request you to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add different authentication filters for each different endpoint.

For `HttpSecurity` you can define something like this, giving the constructor your `UserDetailsService` and passing the authentication manager as well:

```
  .addFilterBefore(new FirstLoginFilter("/api/login/first", userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
  .addFilterBefore(new SecondLoginFilter("/api/login/second", userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
  .addFilterBefore(new AdminLoginFilter("/api/login/admin", userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

The implementation for the filters would look something like this.

Let's start with abstract authentication filter which is parent for all the above ones:

```
public abstract class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    protected final SimpleUserDetailsService userService;

    public LoginFilter(String pattern, SimpleUserDetailsService userService, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(pattern));
        this.userService = userService;
        this.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new FormAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new FormAuthenticationFailureHandler());
    }

    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException {
        User authenticatedUser = this.userService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
        UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuthentication);
    }
}
```

And for example one of the implementations for the actual filter:

```
public class FirstLoginFilter extends LoginFilter {
    public FirstLoginFilter(String pattern, SimpleUserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(pattern, userDetailsService, authManager);
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)(new ObjectMapper()).readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        Authentication authentication = this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(loginToken);
        if(!Role.isRolePresent(authentication.getAuthorities(), Role.YOUR_ROLE)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        } else {
            return authentication;
        }
    }
}
```

My example uses stateless authentication mechanism, so you need to modify the filter accordingly. As I see from your initial example, you are using sessions instead, so in fact it should be much easier for you, since it is already built in to Spring Security

Hope it helps.