# Configure Spring Security for multiple login pages in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }

}
```

The Security Configuration is working fine as expected. Now I am trying to implement 2 login forms each for Admin and User. I tried separating the configuration using **@Order** but landed on the issue mentioned here [Spring boot and spring security multiple login pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575907/spring-boot-and-spring-security-multiple-login-pages)
Any better approach to implement the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to configure two different http elements, let’s create two static classes annotated with @Configuration that extend the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Try configuring something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/admin*")
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .hasRole("ADMIN")

          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/loginAdmin")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/admin_login")
          .failureUrl("/loginAdmin?error=loginError")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/adminPage")

          .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/admin_logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/protectedLinks")
          .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

          .and()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/403")

          .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }
}
And, for normal users:

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class SpringSecurityConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/user*")
          .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
          .hasRole("USER")

          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/loginUser")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/user_login")
          .failureUrl("/loginUser?error=loginError")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/userPage")

          .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/user_logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/protectedLinks")

          .and()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/403")

          .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Refer http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach but become 404 after form commit. Looks like Spring does not notice that shareAccess.html is a loginForm...

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainApp2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/share/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/shareAccess.html")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginFriend").permitAll().failureUrl("/error.html").permitAll().successForwardUrl("/authorizeFriend").and().csrf()
            .disable();
    return http.build();
}
```