# How to solve Multiple formLogin() not being able to find other loginProcessUrl()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

So I have a two login pages. One for Customer and one for AM. I configured 2 login pages in my WebSecurityConfig class. When I try to login in AM using an admin account it works but when I try to login in Customer using a user account the loginProcessingUrl can't be found.

In my **WebSecurityConfig** class:

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig
{

    @Autowired
    MyDBAuthenticationService myDBAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(myDBAuthenticationService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebConfigurationAdapter1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/am/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_AM')")
                    
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/amLogin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/am/postLogin")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/amChatPage")
                    .failureUrl("/amLogin?error")
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/amLogout").logoutSuccessUrl("/amLogoutSuccessful")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and().csrf().disable();

            System.out.println("1st Configurer");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebConfigurationAdapter2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/customer/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')")
                    
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                    
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/customerLogin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/customer/postLogin")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/customerChatPage")
                    .failureUrl("/customerLogin?error")
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/customerLogout").logoutSuccessUrl("/customerLogoutSuccessful")
                    .and().csrf().disable();
            
            System.out.println("2nd Configurer");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my **SpringWebAppInitializer** class:

```html
@Configuration
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(ApplicationContextConfig.class);
        
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
    
}
```

Things that I have done so far are:

- Putting sout() in each static class to know if it gets run. Both did display the sout().
- Change name of both processing url and make it unique. Also change in my jsp file.
- [Spring boot - how to configure multiple login pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856557/spring-boot-how-to-configure-multiple-login-pages)

Here is the result when I login as **AM**:
[image]

Result in netbeans. It enters the Controller but says "null"
[image]

Here is the result when I login as **Customer**:
[image]

Comment: Can someone help me with this? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no differentiation pattern between both http configuration Spring Security is taking the first one login as default, that is the reason why only admin login works, because  it is part of the web security adapter declared as `Order(1)`.

In order to separate both configuration properly it is necessary to define a pattern separation with `.antMatcher`.

here  is one small example to give you an idea of how define both configuration

For admins (see the `.antMatcher` definition it forces to apply the http configuration only to `admin/**` urls.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .antMatcher("/admin/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/adminLogin")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/postLogin")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
                .failureUrl("/adminLogin?error")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/admin/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

    }
```

For customers (see the `.antMatcher` definition it forces to apply the http configuration only to `customer/**` urls.

```
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/customer/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/customerLogin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/customer/postLogin")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/customer/home")
                    .failureUrl("/customerLogin?error")
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutUrl("/customer/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable();

        }
```

There are other examples here: [Example two login pages](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages) and visit the spring security documentation [Multiple Http Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity)

Hope this information helps you.

According to the new configuration you have to do some changes, please review the following configuration, and compare with yours and you will see what is the difference (`antMatcher` is different of `antMatchers`)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig
{

    @Autowired
    MyDBAuthenticationService myDBAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(myDBAuthenticationService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebConfigurationAdapter1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http
                    //.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/am/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_AM')")
                    .antMatcher("/am/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("AM")

                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")

                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/amLogin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/am/postLogin")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/am/chatPage")
                    .failureUrl("/amLogin?error")
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/am/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/amLogoutSuccessful")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .and().csrf().disable();

            System.out.println("1st Configurer");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class WebConfigurationAdapter2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
    {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
        {
            http
                    //.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/customer/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')")
            .antMatcher("/admin/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("CUSTOMER")

                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")

                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/customerLogin")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/customer/postLogin")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/customer/chatPage")
                    .failureUrl("/customerLogin?error")
                    .and().logout().logoutUrl("/customer/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/customerLogoutSuccessful")
                    .and().csrf().disable();

            System.out.println("2nd Configurer");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally remember the controller, you should have the following `RequestMapping` definition at least

`@RequestMapping("/adminLogin")`,  `@RequestMapping("/customerLogin")`, `@RequestMapping("/am/chatPage")`, `@RequestMapping("/customer/chatPage")`

Comment: Thank you but do you have any idea why when it couldn't fine the home jsp file? the /am/amChatPage is the defaultsuccessURL

    @RequestMapping(value = "/am/amChatPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String chatpage(Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("Show AM chatPage");
        return "chatPage";
    }

Comment: According to the reques method you should have a chatPage.jsp file instead of home.jsp it will depends on the view name returned from method that handle the request in this case is chatPage.jsp also you cab update the question with your new security config to see the difference

Comment: Hi, @Daniel C. I updated the websecurityconfig class. I also added the results in both AM and CUSTOMER Login but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Could you please try again, I just add  new information to the answer.

Comment: Hi @Daniel C. Thank you. Both am and customer login pages now redirect successfully but now my problem is it doesn't load the jsp chat pages in both. The error is: Severe:   PWC6117: File "null" not found. Do you have any idea why this occurs?

Comment: Thank you. I'll just post another question for this error because I think it's no longer related to the question. Once again, thank you. Really learned a lot.